# From list of dictionaries to Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Assuming I have the following lists:

```
comp1 = [
    {
        "key": "Chrome",
        "doc_count": 200798745
    },
    {
        "key": "Mobile Safari",
        "doc_count": 79919449
    },    
    {
        "key": "WebKit",
        "doc_count": 60544508
    }
]

comp2 = [
    {
        "key": "Chrome",
        "doc_count": 1231244
    },
    {
        "key": "Mobile Safari",
        "doc_count": 882075
    }
]
```

I'd like to transform them into the following Pandas DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'idx':['Chrome', 'Mobile Safari', 'WebKit'], 'comp1_vals':[200798745, 79919449, 60544508], 'comp2_vals':[1231244, 882075, np.nan]}).set_index('idx')
df
Out[37]: 
               comp1_vals  comp2_vals
idx                                  
Chrome          200798745   1231244.0
Mobile Safari    79919449    882075.0
WebKit           60544508         NaN
```

What would be the best way to approach it?
I thought about transforming each of the lists to a dictionary where the key will become the index of the DataFrame but it looks like it's gonna be messy and contains a lot of if-else statement. Any Pythonic way to do so ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

USe `pandas.merge`:

```
df = pd.merge(pd.DataFrame(comp1), pd.DataFrame(comp2), on='key', how='outer')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
             key  doc_count_x  doc_count_y
0         Chrome    200798745    1231244.0
1  Mobile Safari     79919449     882075.0
2         WebKit     60544508          NaN
```